# Regular expression to match any hyphenated word in a url in PHP

Tags: php, regex, amazon-s3

I'm trying to replace a URL with CloudFront URL.

For example. the URL could be

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/folder/d05c229a73b5c6f169d599652015b1.png

https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-with-hyphen/folder/folder1/d05c229a73b5c6f169d599652015b1.png

https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-with-hyphen/folder-with-hyphen/folder1/d05c229a73b5c6f169d599652015b1.png
```

And then I'll use:

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string)
```

My `$replacement` would be `$1cloudfront.net/$4';`

Here's my `$pattern` so far

```
^(https?:\/\/)(s3.amazonaws.com)\/(\w+-\w+-\w+)\/(<I want the rest of the url>)
```

It will only match `bucket-with-hyphen` but not `bucket-with` & I don't know how to capture the rest of the URL.

Comment: Why not just `[\w-]+` instead?

Comment: @toy In your 3rd example string.. do you want to replace both `bucket-with-hyphen` and `folder-with-hyphen`? and assuming you also want to replace all the words which have atleast one hyphen with `cloudfront.net`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your updated regex that captures "bucket", "bucket-with" or "bucket-with-anything", but won't match "bucket-with-something-else". If you need to capture the 4th option, change `{0,2}` to `*`.

I only added optional non-capturing groups (0 or 2 occurrences):

```
^(https?:\/\/)(s3.amazonaws.com)\/(\w+(?:-\w+){0,2})\/(.*)
                                       ^ ^ ^    ^
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO3mA2/1) and [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/XNIm9P)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If you find my suggestion helpful, please also consider upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
(?<=\/)(?:\w+-)+\w+(?=\/)   //no need to capture whole url here
```

And replace with `cloudfront.net`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sW3qN8/3)